When are tag helper components executed?
TL;DR: In ASP.NET Core, in what moment of the render pipeline are Tag Helper Components executed/processed?
For example, are they executed after their targeted tag is rendered, or after the whole page is rendered? I can't find this information in the official documentation.
Suppose I have a tag helper component that targets <head> elements, like this:
public MyHeadTagHelperComponent : TagHelperComponent
{

    [ViewContext]
    public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }

    public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        if (!context.TagName.Equals("head", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            return;

        // Get some data from the HttpContext
        var someData = ViewContext.HttpContext.Items["SomeData"] as SomeData;

        // Render a <style> tag based on `someData`
        output.PostContent.AppendHtml("<style>/*Some CSS*/</style>");
    }

}

Then, I register my tag helper component as a service:
services.AddTransient<ITagHelperComponent, MyHeadTagHelperComponent>();

And suppose that I also have a tag helper that targets <form> elements, like this:
[HtmlTargetElement("form", Attributes = "my-attribute-name")]
public MyFormTagHelper : TagHelper
{

    [ViewContext]
    public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }

    public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        // Set some data to the HttpContext
        ViewContext.HttpContext.Items["SomeData"] = new SomeData("my data");

        // Do other stuff
    }

}

How do I know that when MyHeadTagHelperComponent is run, the data set by MyFormTagHelper will be present in the HttpContext? In other words, will the tag helper component always run after the tag helper in this case? Does the fact that the tag helper component targets the <head> affect its order of execution over the tag helper (that runs somewhere inside the <body>)?

Tag helpers do not own elements associated with them: they simply participate in the rendering of elements and content. The Tag Helper component is a tag helper that allows you to conditionally modify or add HTML elements in server-side code .And is mainly used to add tags to the global part of the page (such as <head> or <body>).
In the structure of the page, these global part tags usually contain global resources that are important to the layout and behavior of the entire page. These resources often need to be inserted after the page content is generated to ensure that they are available when the page loads. So it can be inferred that he is executed after all Tag Helpers are processed during the view rendering process.
In your example,  I configured the relevant view code:
@addTagHelper *, WebApplication4
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

    <form my-attribute-name="true">
        <!-- This form will be processed by MyFormTagHelper -->
      
        <input type="text" id="inputText" name="inputText" />
    </form>

we can see that: MyHeadTagHelpeComponents will be processed after MyFormTagHelper is executed.When MyHeadTagHelperComponent is executed, MyFormTagHelper has completed the data setting.


When we add the body tag, we can see that it will enter MyHeadTagHelperComponent first before entering MyFormTagHelper:
<body>
    <form my-attribute-name="true">
        <!-- This form will be processed by MyFormTagHelper -->
        <label for="inputText">Enter text:</label>
        <input type="text" id="inputText" name="inputText" />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>




In this case, this affects the order in which they are executed.

The fact that the presence of the <body> tag affects the order or execution is very surprising to me. I didn't expect that. I've been looking at the official source code for tag helpers and tag helper components, and it seems that tag components are ultimately executed by an actual tag helper. The fact that there is no documentation about it and that we see this behavior, makes me think that no particular execution order is to be expected except from what is imposed by Order property (for which the documentation is also not very clear about).
